# Product details not showing as intended

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

I found this php project on github. Vanilla Kit [https://github.com/syndicatefx/vanilla-kit] , is a very simple php powered dynamic website template, I liked the clean folder structure and hence decided to use/try it.

This is the index page on the root directory which is pretty much simple. It calls the page requested by the user (in the folder pages) and replaces the variable $page with page name requested for and displays it.

```
<?php
// Defualt page will always be pages/homepage.html, if not, change this to the name of the file you have created to be the homepage.
$page = 'homepage';

// Get pages based on user input 
if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
    //Assign a variable to a sanitised version of the data passed in the URL
    $tmp_page = basename($_GET['name']); 
    //If the file exists, update $page
    if (file_exists("pages/{$tmp_page}.php")) 
        $page = $tmp_page;
    //If the file does not exist, include notfound page and exit  
    elseif(!file_exists($tmp_page)){
        include 'pages/notfound.php';
        exit;
        }
    }

// Include $page (declared default)
include ("pages/$page.php");
?>
```

The default page which is the homepage fetches products from the products table and displays it.

```
<?php 
// Edit this page's title, description and keywords for SEO
$pagetitle = 'Welcome';
$pagedescription = 'description goes here...';
$pagekeywords = 'keywords,go,here';
// Add a class to body for more CSS power
$bodyclass = 'home';
// Do Not Remove
include 'inc/header.php'; 
?>

<?php 
$dbquery = "SELECT * FROM lbtbl_products"; 
$productresult = $dbconnect->query($dbquery);

if ($productresult->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $productresult->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<div class="prod-cnt prod-box">
<form method="post" action="cartupdate.php">
<h3 class="prod-title">
<a href="productdetail.php?id=<?php echo $row['lbproductId'];?>"><?php echo $row["lbproductName"]; ?></a>
</h3>
<p><?php echo $row["lbproductDescription"];?></p>
<div class="price-cnt">
<div class="prod-price"><img src="images/common/rupees.png" width="7" height="10"/> <?php echo $row["lbproductPrice"];?></div>
Qty <input type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" size="3" />
<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>
<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="<?php echo $row["lbproductSku"];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $current_url;?>" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
<?php }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$dbconnect->close(); ?>
<?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

Everything works fine up till now.

Now, to display the product details I have a page name productdetails.php which is saved in the pages directory as all other pages. The link on the 'homepage' to view the product detail is

```
<a href="productdetail.php?id=<?php echo $row['lbproductId'];?>"><?php echo $row["lbproductName"]; ?></a>
```

But once clicked a 404 not found page is displayed. But if I move the productdetails.php page to the root directory it works. Can anyone help/suggest with a solution. My best guess it has something to do with index.php code after the comment // Get pages based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

Try and share the results.

```
<a href="?name=productdetail.php&id=<?php echo $row['lbproductId'];?>"><?php echo $row["lbproductName"]; ?></a>
```

And in your product detail page you should run your select query with $_GET['id'].
It may work, try and share the results.

Comment: Is your page get blanked ?

Comment: if you look at the index.php page the variable $page is set to the page you requested for and then it simply includes ("pages/$page.php") without changing the url.

Comment: your code, which i already tried, changes the directory of the productdetail.php to www.abc.com/pages/productdetails.php instead of www.abc.com/productdetails.php?id=1 and hence breaks the whole structure.

Comment: Can I check it my own ?

Comment: Yes you can if you don't have any problem